# table input value unrecognised

Tags: javascript, validation, user-input, detect

i was trying to find the sum of the two input values entered to the table and display it on another field on the same table..
but unfortunately javascript shows undefined when i attempt to access the input values for operation..
pls give me a helping hand on this issue..
here is the javascript code::

```js
// JavaScript Document
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var add = function() {

  var tablenode = $("bod");

  var td = tablenode.getElementsByTagName("td");

  var i;
  if (td.lenght > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
      alert(td[i].value);
      //td[i+2].value=td[i].value+td[i+1].value;
    }
  } else
    alert("empty td");



}
var ass = function() {
  alert("reached");

  var con = $("bod");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var dat = document.createElement("td");
  var content = document.createElement("input");
  content.type = "text";
  dat.appendChild(content);
  row.appendChild(dat);
  var data = document.createElement("td");
  var contenta = document.createElement("input");
  contenta.type = "text";
  data.appendChild(contenta);
  row.appendChild(data);
  var datb = document.createElement("td");
  var contentb = document.createElement("input");
  contentb.type = "text";
  datb.appendChild(contentb);
  row.appendChild(datb);
  con.appendChild(row);
}
window.onload = function() {
  //$("new").onclick=add;
  ass();
  $("next").onclick = ass;
  $("next").onmouseover = add;



}
here is the main page::
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="tes.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="200" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>value0</td>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>total</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="bod">
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">grand total
          <input name="grant" type="text" id="grant" />
          <input name="next" type="button" id="next" value="next" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>




  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.value` can't be used for `<td>` elements, only for `<input>` elements. Also, you have a typo: `td.lenght`.

Comment: $("bod"); to $("#bod"); ?

Comment: `if (td.lenght > 0)` is redundant, since if length is 0 then the for loop won't run anyway—even if the typo is fixed. ;-) Better to test `if (tablenode)` since the *$* function may return *null*.

Answer (score 0):

First you have a typo:

```
lenght -> length
```

Second change:

```
td[i].value
```

to:

```
td[i].innerText;
```

Also upon looking on code more closely I think you need to iterate over rows, so you need `i += 3` instead of `i++`

So the overall code would look like this:

```
// JavaScript Document
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var add = function() {

  var tablenode = $("bod");

  var td = tablenode.getElementsByTagName("td");

  var i;
  if (td.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i+=3) {
      alert(td[i].innerText);
      // Assuming you have integer values
      //td[i+2].innerText= parseInt(td[i].innerText) + parseInt(td[i+1].innerText);
      // Assuming you don't have integer values
      //td[i+2].innerText= td[i].innerText + td[i+1].innerText;
    }
  } else
    alert("empty td");



}
var ass = function() {
  alert("reached");

  var con = $("bod");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var dat = document.createElement("td");
  var content = document.createElement("input");
  content.type = "text";
  dat.appendChild(content);
  row.appendChild(dat);
  var data = document.createElement("td");
  var contenta = document.createElement("input");
  contenta.type = "text";
  data.appendChild(contenta);
  row.appendChild(data);
  var datb = document.createElement("td");
  var contentb = document.createElement("input");
  contentb.type = "text";
  datb.appendChild(contentb);
  row.appendChild(datb);
  con.appendChild(row);
}
window.onload = function() {
  //$("new").onclick=add;
  ass();
  $("next").onclick = ass;
  $("next").onmouseover = add;
```

Comment: To iterate over rows, there is the [*table.rows*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/tabular-data.html#dom-table-rows) collection.

Comment: delighted to get the much needed help..didnt know <td> cannot use .value..bt,one ques:what happens if the innertext contains both integer and non integer values...

Comment: Use `isNan` to check if a string is a number, it will return false if it is not a integer

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment.

You can make the *ass* function more concise by doing create and append in one statement. You can also re–use variables:

```
var ass = function() {
  alert("reached");

  var con = $("bod");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell = row.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
  var content = cell.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
  content.type = "text";

  cell = row.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
  content = cell.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
  content.type = "text";

  cell = row.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
  content = cell.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
  content.type = "text";

  con.appendChild(row);
}
```

You can also replace the second two cell appends with:

```
row.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true));
row.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true));
```